# Nodejs random free tcp ports

Tags: node.js, tcp, port

My project need to setup a new port every time a new instance of my class is instantiated.

In Node.js how I can find a free TCP port to set in my new socket server? Or check if my specified port is already used or not.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can bind to a random, free port assigned by the OS by specifying `0` for the port. This way you are not subject to race conditions (e.g. checking for an open port and some process binding to it before you get a chance to bind to it).

Then you can get the assigned port by calling [`server.address().port`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_address).

Example:

```
var net = require('net');

var srv = net.createServer(function(sock) {
  sock.end('Hello world\n');
});
srv.listen(0, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + srv.address().port);
});
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but in this case for test a port if is available I'm need using a try/catch and retry, no?

Comment: If you want a specific port, just try listening on it and check for the error event. If you get an error and `error.code === 'EADDRINUSE'` then you know the port is in use.

Comment: Works just as well for `http.createServer(...).listen()` !

Comment: I like to set the port number in an environment variable but fall back to a random port if not specified: `srv.listen(process.env.PORT || 0);`.

Answer (score 27):

For Express app:

```
const app = require('express')();

const server = app.listen(0, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port:', server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 19):

I use this compact form:

```js
import net from "net"

async function getPortFree() {
    return new Promise( res => {
        const srv = net.createServer();
        srv.listen(0, () => {
            const port = srv.address().port
            srv.close((err) => res(port))
        });
    })
}
```

use:

```js
const PORT = await getPortFree()
```

Answer (score 6):

**Port Finder Library:**

https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder

I suggest you use `portfinder` library, it has over 10 million downloads in a week.

By default `portfinder` library will start searching from 8000 and scan until the maximum port number (65535) is reached.

```
const portfinder = require('portfinder');

portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    //
    // `port` is guaranteed to be a free port
    // in this scope.
    //
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To find an opened TCP's port you can use the module [portastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portastic)

You can find a port like this:

```
port = require('portastic');

options = {
    min : 8000,
    max : 8005
}

port.find(options, function(err, data){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It seems like `portfinder` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/portfinder) would be a better module to use for this case. It even has included TypeScript types!

Answer (score 1):

I've used the accepted answer on numerous occasions when building apps that run locally - thanks @mscdex. However, I had a use case recently when it would be preferable to stick to a given port if possible, but still to fallback to another port if that one is taken.

The reason for this is I wanted to save app preferences using localStorage, which is restricted to the same site, with the same port for security. Therefore, I wanted to always use port 3000 when possible, but if needed fallback to 3001, or 3002, etc. until one is available. If the port being used is not 3000, then I fallback to a copy of the app preferences stored on the user's hard disk.

I do this with this pattern:

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function(req,res){ ... })

const config = {
  port: 3000,
  launched: false,
};

serverListen(server, config.port);

function serverListen(server, port){
  server.on('error', e => {
    console.log(`port ${config.port} is taken`)
    config.port +=1;
    server.close();
    serverListen(server, config.port);
  }).listen(port, function() {
    if (config.launched){
      return;
    }
    console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    launchBrowser();
    config.launched = true;
  });
}
```

`launchBrowser()` is just a function that launches the browser to `'http://127.0.0.1:' + server.address().port`

The app is a simple local server + browser app. With the browser being the GUI and the server doing the modification of files etc. on the user's harddrive.

Comment: This is nice, but probably could error out after having tried 10,100, etc, ports rather than all ~65k...

Answer (score 0):

### Await'ing the port

For those of you trying to do this "synchronously", with downstream code dependent on the `port` that is chosen by the OS (*e.g. while creating a test server and passing the port to tests*), the following recipe has served me well:

```
export const sleepForPort = async (httpServer: Server, ms: number): Promise<number> => {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
    httpServer.listen(0, async () => {
      try{
        let addr = (httpServer.address() as AddressInfo | null)
        while(! (addr && addr.port) ) {
          await sleep(ms);
          addr = httpServer.address() as AddressInfo | null
        }
        resolve(addr.port);
      }catch(e){
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  });
}

const sleep = (ms: number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

If running integration tests against a live server, this allows us to `await` the port number becoming available, and return this so our `testClient` can hit `localhost` on this port!

```
export const setupTests = async () => {
  const app = createExpressApp(...);
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer); // Testing graphql subscriptions
  const port = await sleepForPort(httpServer, 100);
  return {port}
}

describe("Http server test", () => {
  let port: number;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    {port} = await setupTests()
  })
  it("Hits the right port", () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:${port}/testing`)
    expect(res).toBeDefined()
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  }
})
```