How to change the port number if it is already taken?
I'm trying to build my current project it in a way so my friends can create servers on one network so we can connect to each other (LAN communication, pretty much). The only problem is when I run my program in two terminal windows, my second run fails and throws errors at me because ports are already taken, which is logical.
I am working with Vite, express, and ws. This is one of my server's code.
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws')

const sockserver1 = new WebSocketServer({ port: 311 })
sockserver1.on('connection', ws => {
    sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
        client.send(`A new player connection has been established`);
    })

    ws.on('message', data => {
        sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
            client.send(`${data}`)
        })
    })

    ws.on('close', () => {
        sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
            client.send(`A player has disconnected`)
        })
    })

    ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log('websocket error')
    }
});

When I run this the second time, it will fail and say that port ::311 is taken. How can I add 1 to the port number till I find one that isn't taken? I have notice Vite does this.

What does setting the port at 0 do?

It... doesn't give me an error for that server! The next server gives me an error since it is set to something other then 0.

Localhost:0 is restricted, though.

This question is similar to: Nodejs random free tcp ports. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jabaa Uh oh, yeah this might be a duplicate. I tried to see if there was a question already like it

"How can I add 1 to the port number till I find one that isn't taken? I have notice Vite does this." Vite is open source. You can check it in the source code. https://github.com/vitejs/vite

I don't think I got recommended that question. How do I close a question?

I'm not sure, if you can close your own questions with your reputation. You can either delete it or wait until others close it.

Well, I'm satisfied with Anston's answer, so I'll be okay with my question being closed. Thank you everyone!

Keep in mind that the accepted answer can cause race conditions. It's okay for a hobby project, but in production this is a bug.

Yes. I will keep this in mind. Thanks Jabaa!

@Alex look at my revised answer

This question is similar to: Javascript: Can I open websocket server connection at random port. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try to make a method that tests the current port and tries the next one if it's taken.
Here is what that would look like:
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');
const net = require('net');

function findAvailablePort(startPort, callback) {
    const server = net.createServer();
    server.listen(startPort, () => {
        server.once('close', () => {
            callback(startPort);
        });
        server.close();
    });
    server.on('error', () => {
        findAvailablePort(startPort + 1, callback);
    });
}

findAvailablePort(311, (availablePort) => {
    const sockserver1 = new WebSocketServer({ port: availablePort });
    console.log(`WebSocket server started on port ${availablePort}`);

    sockserver1.on('connection', ws => {
        sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
            client.send(`A new player connection has been established`);
        });

        ws.on('message', data => {
            sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
                client.send(`${data}`);
            });
        });

        ws.on('close', () => {
            sockserver1.clients.forEach(client => {
                client.send(`A player has disconnected`);
            });
        });

        ws.onerror = function () {
            console.log('websocket error');
        }
    });
});


This could cause a race condition. The port could be free when you create the the server in the test function and be used by another program when you create the actual server. You should either use the actual server for the test or ask the operating system for a port. Your approach can fail from time to time. Depending on the number of parallel servers, you have to test many ports before you find a free one.

Have you tried it, with port 0? The OP wrote, they've tried it and it doesn't work in the way, you've described it.

I tried it and it works. I don’t understand. Where does Alex say it doesn’t work?

I mean do I need to send screenshots of it working? What did I do? Was it my unnecessary comments earlier?

I've downvoted, because the OP explicitly wrote in a comment, that port: 0 doesn't work for them. If it should work, the question requires more clarification. An answer, that doesn't work for the OP, is not helpful.

Is it when he said localhost:0 is restricted? I’m not even sure what that means

Okayyyy then. Answer reverted

Yes, that's what I've meant. You asked the OP to use port 0 and the answer was that the first server was started on port 0 and the second server crashed. That doesn't make much sense, but I haven't tried it and I trusted the OP. I reverted my downvote.

It’s just weird because it worked when I ran it. It uses a different port each time. Usually the port is 30 thousand some on windows

Maybe the problem is, that I trusted the OP's statement. Maybe the OP did something wrong.

Here is the message I get when I try to open it, (I probably should have sent this before) "This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection." Chrome can't access the server. I am not sure why port 0 works either. It does this from port 0 to port 9. Port 10 works just fine. Is this another question I should ask? See if someone else knows what the issue may be?

@Alex You shouldn't try to open the address with port 0. Port 0 doesn't exist. It's a special value to signal the operating system that you want a random free port. The operating system selects a port for the server. You have to find out this port and use this port in your client. Please provide more details and debugging information in the future.  "It... doesn't give me an error for that server! The next server gives me an error since it is set to something other then 0. Localhost:0 is restricted, though." is not helpful.

I think he doesn’t really care about this question anymore now that he has his answer. I mean, I’ve been like that before

No, I do. I'm trying to help you understand what I'm doing so we all know what is going on.

@jabaa Good to know for future reference. About the comment that wasn't helpful for you, what I meant is that when I run the script twice, I don't get an error that port 0 is already taken, but I do get an error that the other ports for the other servers are taken. I haven't told you about the other servers, so my mistake.

I'm new to websites like this, so I'm trying to build good conversation habits (especially for Stack Overflow).

@Alex So would my newer answer work for you or not? That’s what I’d really like to know

Yes, it works. I checked your most recent edit, and it works, so thank you, Anston Sorensen and Jabaa for your time. I'll still keep in mind about the race condition. And thankfully my project is just for my friends, so I can warn them.

@Alex The question is, if port: 0 also works. That would be the correct answer. It doesn't test ports and it doesn't have a race condition. If I correctly understand, the comments under your question are wrong. The servers started correctly, but you didn't know the correct URL for the client.

I did some research, and I realize how naive I was on the subject. Now I understand what you guys meant about port 0. It was information going right over my head. How do I know which port it chose when I listen for port 0?

@Alex You can find it in the accepted answer in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050404/16540390 If you don't find it in the documentation or on Stack Overflow, check the source code: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/websocket-server.js#L143

Then yes, this works. Thank you for taking the time to help me understand.

@AnstonSorensen Both your answers are correct. I just misunderstood what port 0 was used for. Thanks for your answer. You and jabba saved me a lot of time.
